# A for loop that creates txt files for each point in a netCDF4 file

Tags: python-3.x, loops, netcdf4

1. I have a netCDF4 file with a gridded daily relative humidity data in it. I downloaded the data from the [ERA5](https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/cdsapp#!/dataset/reanalysis-era5-pressure-levels?tab=form) site.

The cell size (X, Y) is 0.25, 0.25

The data goes from 01-01-2001 until 12-31-2018

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
from osgeo import gdal
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Read in the netCDF file

data = Dataset(r'C:\Users\obarresi\Desktop\ERA\moisture\humidity.nc', 'r') # Select path in which your file is located

data.variales.keys()

dict_keys(['longitude', 'latitude', 'time', 'r'])

# Indicate your path

os.chdir('/Users/obarresi/Desktop/ERA/moisture') # This is the location where the SWAT+ files will be saved
```

2. So, when I read each variable of the netCDF4 file I'd get a latitude, longitude, time and the relative humidity. I put the array of the relative humidity data given by the netCDF4.

```
lat = data.variables['latitude'][:]
lon = data.variables['longitude'][:]
rh = data.variables['r'][:]

print(rh)

[[[ 75.06203241  75.03655509  76.3460895  ...  72.56525473  72.07099466
    72.47353637]
  [ 75.02381643  74.87350022  75.86711583 ...  70.91177645  70.62133496
    70.7665557 ]
  [ 75.45183546  75.05948468  75.72953828 ...  68.41499877  68.69524932
    69.37039839]
  ...
  [ 94.50377781  95.91012605  96.81457103 ...  73.24804699  74.02510535
    75.42635813]
  [ 94.35091387  95.94834204  97.00565096 ...  71.6251415   72.09647198
    73.17416276]
  [ 94.61587803  96.10375371  97.08208293 ...  70.53980753  71.31941362
    72.21876313]]
```

4. My question is: How can I code a loop that will give me a txt file with the daily value of relative humidity of each point (or station) in the netCDF4 file?
   I'd like that the content of each txt file will be like this:

```
20010101 # the initial date
75.06  # value of the first day (20010102)
80.36  # value of the second day (20010103)
40.32  # value of the third day  (20010104)

...

45.35 # value of the last day of measure
```

So the output will only contain the initial date like so `file.write("20010101"+"\n")` and then the value of relative humidity.

Thank you so much for your help

Comment: I suggest that you break this down into smaller pieces. I can help to step away from your computer and get a pen and paper to write these smaller pieces down in words. It looks like you figured out how to read data from a file. Now you need to learn how to open a file to write to and then loop over a list to write its contents to a file. There are already python tutorials and other documentation that can help you do this. Which part are you struggling with?

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I actually came up with an answer although I need to debug it